Traces are not available on Jaeger with AWS otel collector
I have a lambda with a setup to collect telemetry data with OpenTelemetry libraries. To test it locally I have a docker compose file where I defined 3 services:

aws-otel-collector to collect traces
jaeger to visualize traces
prometheus to collect metrics

The problem is that Jaeger is not receiving any traces from the collector. But If I run only jaeger services I am able to see the traces coming from the lambda application.
Here the files:
    public Function(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _tracerProvider = Sdk.CreateTracerProviderBuilder()
            .AddHttpClientInstrumentation(options =>
            {
                options.EnrichWithHttpRequestMessage = (activity, request) =>
                {
                    if (request?.RequestUri?.Host != null)
                    {
                        activity.DisplayName = request.RequestUri.Host;
                    }
                    activity.SetTag("http.method", request?.Method);
                    activity.SetTag("http.user_agent", request?.Headers.UserAgent.ToString());
                    activity.SetTag("http.url", request?.RequestUri?.ToString());
                };
                options.EnrichWithHttpResponseMessage = (activity, response) =>
                {
                    activity.SetTag("http.status_code", (int)response.StatusCode);
                };
            })
            .AddAWSInstrumentation()
            .AddConsoleExporter()
            .AddOtlpExporter()
            .AddAWSLambdaConfigurations()
            .Build();
        Sdk.SetDefaultTextMapPropagator(new AWSXRayPropagator());
    }

version: '3.9'
services:
  jaeger:
    image: jaegertracing/all-in-one:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "16686:16686"
      - "14268"
      - "14250:14250"
    environment:
      - COLLECTOR_OTLP_ENABLED=true
      - METRICS_STORAGE_TYPE=prometheus
      - PROMETHEUS_SERVER_URL=http://prometheus:9090
      - PROMETHEUS_QUERY_NAMESPACE=${PROMETHEUS_QUERY_NAMESPACE:-}
      - PROMETHEUS_QUERY_DURATION_UNIT=${PROMETHEUS_QUERY_DURATION_UNIT:-}
      - PROMETHEUS_QUERY_NORMALIZE_CALLS=true
      - PROMETHEUS_QUERY_NORMALIZE_DURATION=true
  aws-ot-collector:
    image: amazon/aws-otel-collector:latest
    command: ["--config=/etc/otel-agent-config.yaml"]
    volumes:
      - ./otel-collector-config.yaml:/etc/otel-agent-config.yaml
      - ~/.aws:/root/.aws
    ports:
      - "1888:1888"   # pprof extension
      - "8888:8888"   # Prometheus metrics exposed by the collector
      - "8889:8889"   # Prometheus exporter metrics
      - "13133:13133" # health_check extension
      - "4317:4317"   # OTLP gRPC receiver
      - "55670:55679" # zpages extension
    depends_on:
      - jaeger
  
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus.yaml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"

receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:

exporters:
  debug:
    verbosity: detailed
  prometheus:
    endpoint: "0.0.0.0:8889"
    namespace: promexample
    const_labels:
      label1: value1
  otlp:
    endpoint: jaeger:4317
    tls:
      insecure: true

processors:
  batch:

extensions:
  health_check:
  pprof:
    endpoint: :1888
  zpages:
    endpoint: :55679

service:
  extensions: [pprof, zpages, health_check]
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [debug, otlp]
    metrics:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [debug, prometheus]

I tried also with otel/opentelemetry-collector-contrib but nothing changed.
I read/followed a lot of resources, guides and all of them have basically this configuration

Please update your configs with specific version numbers of the containers, latest is meaningless in this context
